# Sqlite sum every 3 rows

Tags: sqlite

I have the following data in DB:

[capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOYds.jpg)

I want to make the data appear as follows using SQLite:
[capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXB6Z.jpg)

`300  230  250` is a carry forward row of totals from one table in DB, which appears as the first row as per SQLite `Select sum(Red), sum(Green), sum(Blue)` command, followed by new entries from another table in DB using `Select Red, Green, Blue command`.
Now, I want a fresh total of each column after 3 entries, FOLLOWED BY repeat of this total, then 3 entries followed by same, and so on and so forth.
I have 600 fresh entries, which I need to display in this fashion. Thanks

Comment: What if the number of rows is not a multiple of 3?

Comment: Please read the tag wiki info for the tag you used https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info and provide a MRE as described there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function SUM() to get the partial totals.
Create CTEs for the partial totals, so that they are doubled except the last one and use UNION ALL with the rows of the table to return the final result:

```
WITH 
  cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowid) rn ,
           SUM(Red) OVER (ORDER BY rowid) sum_red,
           SUM(Green) OVER (ORDER BY rowid) sum_green,
           SUM(Blue) OVER (ORDER BY rowid) sum_blue
    FROM tablename
  ),
  totals1 AS (
    SELECT rn, sum_red, sum_green, sum_blue 
    FROM cte
    WHERE (rn > 1) AND ((rn - 1) % ? = 0 OR (rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM cte))) 
  ),
  totals2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM totals1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM totals1
    WHERE rn < (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM totals1)
  ),
  empty AS (
    SELECT 1 col, null Red, null Green, null Blue
    WHERE (SELECT (COUNT(*) - 1) % ? FROM tablename) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col + 1, null, null, null
    FROM empty
    WHERE col < ? - (SELECT (COUNT(*) - 1) % ? FROM tablename) 
  )
SELECT Red, Green, Blue 
FROM (  
  SELECT 1 ord, rn, Red, Green, Blue FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename), Red, Green, Blue
  FROM empty  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, rn, sum_red, sum_green, sum_blue FROM totals2
)  
ORDER BY rn, ord
```

Change `?` with the number of rows of each bucket.
Note that since there is not a column in your table that denotes the order of the rows I use `rowid`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=13edcff76b92097ff13cd9c78539a318).
Results (for 4 rows in bucket):

```
>  Red | Green | Blue
> ---: | ----: | ---:
>  300 |   230 |  250
>    5 |     6 |    4
>    4 |     3 |    2
>    4 |     3 |    5
>    6 |     5 |    4
>  319 |   247 |  265
>  319 |   247 |  265
>    4 |     5 |    6
>    3 |     6 |    7
>    2 |     5 |    6
>    5 |     4 |    3
>  333 |   267 |  287
>  333 |   267 |  287
>    3 |     9 |   12
>      |       |                
>      |       |                
>      |       |                
>  336 |   276 |  299
```

Comment: Hi forpas..this works well if there are 9 rows, with row of 3 between totals..if there are 10 rows, then I want  last and second last row  to be blank. With your solution, total is appearing immediately after 10th row

Comment: Similarly, with 10 rows and rows of 4, by altering your code  WHERE (rn > 1) AND ((rn - 1) % 3 = 0 OR (rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM cte) to  WHERE (rn > 1) AND ((rn - 1) % 4 = 0 OR (rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM cte), the result should leave 2 empty rows before last total(4+4+2+2blanks)..Thanks

Comment: @harry post sample data and expected results for that case.

Comment: @forpas...your result on left, desired result on right with 4 rows https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW7lL.jpg

Comment: or your code used for 9 rows with 4 rows between totals  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgGAU.jpg

Comment: @forpas...fantastic..thank you for your time and seamless efforts and response..it is a very complicated code and I can only begin to understand its intricacies..you are truly an Expert..